# JS: Variable appears to be a string but displays as: "[object Object]"

Tags: javascript, node.js, string

I am parsing wikipedia documents and using the npm [html-to-text](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-text) converter package to extract just the text from various wikipedia pages. I am encountering issues when trying to log / send this content to be used on the client side.

Here is my implementation with the npm package:

```
 var stringer = htmltext.fromString(data, {
              wordwrap: 130
 });

 console.log(stringer) // returns [object Object]
 console.log(typeof stringer); // returns string
 console.log(util.inspect(stringer)); // returns '[object Object]'
```

As you can see in the comments, the first console log appears to represent the variable as an object but the second shows that is a string. How can this be?

Comment: Try using console.dir instead of log

Comment: Try `stringer.toString();` .

Comment: `console.dir` gave me '[object Object]' and `stringer.toString()` gave me [object Object]. Not really sure what to make of that.

Comment: Maybe it is a string and the string content is legitimately `[object Object]`?  I would look further up the stack, finger pointing at at the library, if your not doing anything else in-between getting the string and logging that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you passing into `htmltext.fromString()`?

Are you sure you aren't passing an object into there which is converting to string as [object Object]?

For example, if I type the following into a node console I get what you're seeing. :)

```
 > var htmltotext = require("html-to-text")
 undefined
 > htmltotext.fromString({})
 '[object Object]'
 >
```

The [usage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-text#usage) illustrates that `.fromString()` expects a string input.

Comment: Turns out I was passing in an object. I though it was a string but I was wrong. Now I feel dumb.